# Why doesn't the Undo/Redo History Widget run my custom undo/redo methods?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, undo-redo

We're writing a Python plugin for QGIS 2.8.3. I've derived a class from `QUndoCommand` to contain "undo-able" work. When I push it onto the undo stack, its `redo` method gets called as expected, but QGIS doesn't call the `undo` method when I click Undo in the Undo/Redo History widget, nor call the `redo` method again when I click Redo.

The code looks like:

```
class TestUndoCommand(QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestUndoCommand, self).__init__("TestUndoCommand")

    def redo(self):
        super(TestUndoCommand, self).redo()
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Redo", "Redo")

    def undo(self):
        super(TestUndoCommand, self).undo()
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Undo", "Undo")

undoAddCmd = TestUndoCommand()
someLayer.undoStack().push(undoAddCmd)
```

What am I missing?